# they should have been

Tags: phrase-meaning

Does "they should have been" mean "they should have been (given notice)"?

> "Why are they only counting them whenever the place is cleared out with no witnesses," Pick asked.

> 11Alive was able to determine that this part is true. The media and **the party monitors were not given notice** that counting would continue into the early morning hours and **they should have been**.

Source:  [FACT-CHECKING CLAIMS ABOUT FULTON COUNTY'S ELECTION | THESE 'SUITCASES' ARE ACTUALLY BALLOT CONTAINERS](https://www.11alive.com/amp/article/news/politics/elections/fact-checking-claims-about-fulton-countys-election/85-89c150d2-c917-44b6-b7ab-a29dd9dcb888)

Comment: Yes, it certainly does.

Answer (score 1):

> Does "they should have been" mean "they should have been (given notice)"?

Yes, it certainly does.

Comment: Does "they should have been" mean "they should have been (given notice)"? Yes!!